# psycopg2 insert python dictionary as json

Tags: python, postgresql, dictionary, psycopg2

I want to insert a python dictionary as a json into my postgresql database (via python and psycopg2).

I have:

```py
thedictionary = {'price money': '$1', 'name': 'Google', 'color': '', 'imgurl': 'http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo225.png', 'charateristics': 'No Description', 'store': 'google'}

cur.execute("INSERT INTO product(store_id, url, price, charecteristics, color, dimensions) VALUES (%d, %s, %s, %d, %s, %s)", (1,  'http://www.google.com', '$20', thedictionary, 'red', '8.5x11'))
```

And it gives the error message:

> cur.execute("INSERT INTO product(store_id, url, price, charecteristics, color, dimensions) VALUES (%d, %s, %s, %d, %s, %s)", (1,  'http://www.google.com', '$20', thedictionary, 'red', '8.5x11'))
>       psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'

I am not sure how to proceed from here.
I cannot find anything on the internet about how to do this exact kind of thing and I am very new to psycopg2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45150668/3598837

Comment: @bibangamba is that a link that people using the more recent postgres versions should look at?

Comment: I think it's fine. I'm using postgres 10 and it worked without any issue

Comment: @Felipe Augusto has the best answer, thanks!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```py
cur.execute("INSERT INTO product(store_id, url, price, charecteristics, color, dimensions) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (1,  'http://www.google.com', '$20', json.dumps(thedictionary), 'red', '8.5x11'))
```

That will solve your problem. However, you really should be storing keys and values in their own separate columns. To retrieve the dictionary, do:

```py
cur.execute('select charecteristics from product where store_id = 1')
dictionary = json.loads(cur.fetchone()[0])
```

Comment: If you'd like avoid hardcoding all of the `%s` placeholders you can use `', '.join(["%s"] * len(columns))` as well after getting the columns in the form of a list with something like the following: `columns = list(dictionary.keys())`.

Answer (score 29):

From the [psycopg docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html):

> Note You can use register_adapter() to adapt any Python dictionary to JSON, either registering Json or any subclass or factory creating a compatible adapter:
>
> `psycopg2.extensions.register_adapter(dict, psycopg2.extras.Json)`
>
> This setting is global though, so it is not compatible with similar adapters such as the one registered by register_hstore(). Any other object supported by JSON can be registered the same way, but this will clobber the default adaptation rule, so be careful to unwanted side effects.

So, in my case what I did was:

```py
from psycopg2.extras import Json
from psycopg2.extensions import register_adapter

register_adapter(dict, Json)
```

It worked like a charm.

Comment: from psycopg2.extras import Json is needed to make it work, but this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 21):

update 2023-12-25

For now, I prefer using `sqlalchemy` to insert JSON data into PostgreSQL.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# create_engine
PGDATABASE='PGDATABASE'
PGHOST="192.168.100.100"
PGUSER="PGUSER"
PGPASSWORD="PGPASSWORD"
PGPORT='5432'
pg_engine = create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://{PGUSER}:{PGPASSWORD}@{PGHOST}:{PGPORT}/{PGDATABASE}')

# create test table
with pg_engine.connect() as conn:
    sql = '''
    BEGIN;
    -- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS url_test;
    CREATE TABLE url_test (
        "id" Serial, 
        "log_data" json,
        "cat_name" text,
        "created_at" timestamptz default now()
    );
    COMMIT;
    '''
    conn.execute(sql)
    logging.info("url_test created")

# 2023-12-14 sqlalchemy==2.0  not work 
# pip install --upgrade 'pandas<1.4' 'sqlalchemy<1.4' is ok
with pg_engine.connect() as conn:
    item = {
        'log_data': '{"abc":1, "de":null}',
        'cat_name': "demo-10%-'a",
        'created_at' : '2023-07-09',
    }
    tbl_name = 'src.url_test'
    sql = f'''
    INSERT INTO {tbl_name} (log_data, cat_name)
    VALUES (%(log_data)s, %(cat_name)s)
    ''' 
    conn.execute(sql, **item)
    logging.info("PG DUMP")
```

---

Answer in 2020.

You can use `psycopg2.extras.Json` to convert dict to json that postgre accept.

```
from psycopg2.extras import Json

thedictionary = {'price money': '$1', 
'name': 'Google', 'color': '', 'imgurl': 'http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo225.png', 'charateristics': 'No Description', 'store': 'google'}

item ={
    "store_id":1,
    "url": 'http://www.google.com', 
    "price":'$20', 
    "charecteristics":Json(thedictionary), 
    "color":'red', 
    "dimensions":'8.5x11'
}

def sql_insert(tableName, data_dict):
    '''
    INSERT INTO product (store_id,  url,  price,  charecteristics,  color,  dimensions)
    VALUES (%(store_id)s, %(url)s, %(price)s, %(charecteristics)s, %(color)s, %(dimensions)s );
    '''
    sql = '''
        INSERT INTO %s (%s)
        VALUES (%%(%s)s );
        '''   % (tableName, ',  '.join(data_dict),  ')s, %('.join(data_dict))
    return sql

tableName = 'product'
sql = sql_insert(tableName, item)

cur.execute(sql, item)
```

For more information, you can see [the official document](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.Json).

```
class psycopg2.extras.Json(adapted, dumps=None)

    An ISQLQuote wrapper to adapt a Python object to json data type.

    Json can be used to wrap any object supported by the provided dumps function. If none is provided, the standard json.dumps() is used (simplejson for Python < 2.6; getquoted() will raise ImportError if the module is not available).

    dumps(obj)
    Serialize obj in JSON format.

    The default is to call json.dumps() or the dumps function provided in the constructor. You can override this method to create a customized JSON wrapper.
```

Comment: Apparently, this doesnt work with INT datatype. I tried this but I get an error:
InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: ""
LINE 3:         VALUES ('', 'Verlängerung',...)
Any ideas?

Comment: @Nofy You could refer to my last post.

Comment: Done with same, successfully inserted the charecteristics.
now how to select charecteristics from the product and print all imgurl.
my column is of type text.
when I run the select charecteristics  from product getting the result as a string, not a dict.
How to fetch as a dict and get each object.

Comment: you can use `select charecteristics::json from product` if the format is json style. or in python, use `json.loads`(json str) or `eval`(dict str).

Comment: Wraping dictionary input as `Json(thedictionary)` before inserting into Postgres DB did the trick.

Comment: link to latest docs (2.9.5): [class psycopg2.extras.Json](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.Json)

Answer (score 4):

Starting from version 2.5 of psycopg2 you can use Json adapter.

> Psycopg can adapt Python objects to and from the PostgreSQL json and jsonb types. With PostgreSQL 9.2 and following versions adaptation is available out-of-the-box.

```
from psycopg2.extras import Json
curs.execute("insert into mytable (jsondata) values (%s)", [ Json({'a': 100}) ] )
```

For more information see the docs:
https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#json-adaptation

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the dict type to json_str, use `json.dumps(adict)`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import json
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine_nf = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@192.168.100.120:5432/database')
sql_read = lambda sql: pd.read_sql(sql, engine_nf)
sql_execute = lambda sql: pd.io.sql.execute(sql, engine_nf)

sql = '''
CREATE TABLE if not exists product (
    store_id  int
    , url  text
    , price text
    , charecteristics json
    , color text
    , dimensions text
)
'''
_ = sql_execute(sql)

thedictionary = {'price money': '$1', 'name': 'Google', 
    'color': '', 'imgurl': 'http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo225.png', 
    'charateristics': 'No Description', 
    'store': 'google'}

sql = '''
INSERT INTO product(store_id, url, price, charecteristics, color, dimensions) 
VALUES (%d, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
''' % (1, 'http://www.google.com', '$20', 
       json.dumps(thedictionary), 'red', '8.5x11')

sql_execute(sql)

sql = '''
select * 
from product
'''
df = sql_read(sql)
df
    #   store_id    url price   charecteristics color   dimensions
    # 0 1   http://www.google.com   $20 {'price money': '$1', 'name': 'Google', 'color...   red 8.5x11

charecteristics = df['charecteristics'].iloc[0]
type(charecteristics)
    # dict
```

In fact, I like another way to dump data to postgres.

```py
import io
import csv
def df2db(df_a, table_name, engine):
    output = io.StringIO()
    # ignore the index
    df_a.to_csv(output, sep='\t', index = False, header = False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    output.getvalue()
    # jump to start of stream
    output.seek(0)

    #engine ---- from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    connection = engine.raw_connection() 
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    # null value become ''
    cursor.copy_from(output,table_name,null='')
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()


df = sql_read('select * from product')
type(df.charecteristics.iloc[0])
df.charecteristics = df.charecteristics.map(json.dumps)

# dump pandas DataFrame to postgres
df2db(df, 'product', engine_nf)
df_end = sql_read('select * from product')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, the error means that you're trying to push a `dict` value into a column type that cannot accept it ( `TEXT` etc .. )

The accepted solution was correct to convert it from JSON/dict -> string in order to store it.

BUT, there is a column type that can accept it: JSON

I would suggest to create a JSON field in the first place in order to keep dict-like objects. and the reason is that:

1. you can simply push the dict as is to the DB w/o `json.dumps` or other conversions ( because remember that when you push - you need to `json.dumps` but when you *read* it in python later on you need `json.loads` ( to convert back from string -> dict ).
2. You can *query* its content in a real JSON column, what you cannot do when it's a string.

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/

So when creating a column i would suggest make a default of `{}` vs NULL:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
   ...
   my_json_col JSON default '{}'::JSON
   ...
)
```

Answer (score -2):

Is there a particular reason you want to have each key as its own column? Postgres lets you perform direct query operations within a single column containing valid JSON or JSONB

This means you can simply create a 2 column DB with ID (primary key) and metadata and then perform queries such as:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE metadata @> '{"key": "value"}';
```

[Here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/) is a good resource for you.