# Insert JSON data from REST API into PostgreSQL table using Python

Tags: python, json, postgresql, rest

I tried to insert each element of the json api into my postgres table.

But I get the follwoing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/myname/Documents/repos/docker-playground/parse_json_to_postgres.py", line 20, in <module>
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT into catfacts(data) VALUES (  {cat_fact}  )")
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: INSERT into catfacts(data) VALUES (  {'status': {'verified':...
                                             ^
```

**My postgres table:**

```
CREATE TABLE cat_facts (
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    data jsonb NOT NULL
);
```

**My Python code to insert the data into the table:**

```
import requests, json, psycopg2  


cat_facts_json = requests.get('https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts').json


conn = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                password="password",
                                host="localhost",
                                port="5432",
                                database="postgres")

cursor = conn.cursor()

for cat_fact in cat_facts_json():
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT into catfacts(data) VALUES ( \' {cat_fact} \' )")
```

API = https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts

**What I am trying to achieve:**

```
INSERT INTO cat_facts(data) VALUES ('{"status":{"verified":true,"sentCount":1},"type":"cat","deleted":false,"_id":"58e008800aac31001185ed07","user":"58e007480aac31001185ecef","text":"Wikipedia has a recording of a cat meowing, because why not?","__v":0,"source":"user","updatedAt":"2020-08-23T20:20:01.611Z","createdAt":"2018-03-06T21:20:03.505Z","used":false}');
INSERT INTO cat_facts(data) VALUES ('{"status":{"verified":true,"sentCount":1},"type":"cat","deleted":false,"_id":"58e008630aac31001185ed01","user":"58e007480aac31001185ecef","text":"When cats grimace, they are usually \"taste-scenting.\" They have an extra organ that, with some breathing control, allows the cats to taste-sense the air.","__v":0,"source":"user","updatedAt":"2020-08-23T20:20:01.611Z","createdAt":"2018-02-07T21:20:02.903Z","used":false},{"status":{"verified":true,"sentCount":1},"type":"cat","deleted":false,"_id":"58e00a090aac31001185ed16","user":"58e007480aac31001185ecef","text":"Cats make more than 100 different sounds whereas dogs make around 10.","__v":0,"source":"user","updatedAt":"2020-08-23T20:20:01.611Z","createdAt":"2018-02-11T21:20:03.745Z","used":false}');

....
```

[image]

Comment: Did you have a look at the answers here? [psycopg2 insert python dictionary as json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796332/psycopg2-insert-python-dictionary-as-json)

Comment: In addition to @StefanoFrazzetto post, see this [Query parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) for why you should not be using formatted strings.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I like the documentation part where it says: "Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint."

Comment: Yes, I tried that                                                                                                           for cat_fact in cat_facts_json():
    cursor.execute("INSERT into catfacts(data) VALUES ( %s )" % json.dumps(cat_fact) ) which didnt work still the same error.

Comment: And this for cat_fact in cat_facts_json():
    sql = "INSERT into catfacts(data) VALUES ( %s )"

    cursor.execute(sql,cat_fact)
retuns:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/user/Documents/repos/docker-playground/parse_json_to_postgres.py", line 33, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql,cat_fact)
TypeError: dict is not a sequence

Answer (score 1):

See here [JSON Adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json).

So something like:

```
from psycopg2.extras import Json

cursor.execute("INSERT into catfacts(data) VALUES (%s)", [Json(cat_fact)])
```

Comment: Not quite there yet, but closer. 
The print works and it return each cat fact object. 
The insert is somehow not working.

for cat_fact in cat_facts_json:
    print(cat_fact)
    cursor.execute("INSERT into cat_facts(data) VALUES (%s)", [Json(cat_fact)])

And missed () in my get query which is now requests.get('https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts').json() instead of requests.get('https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts').json. Thanks already Adrian

Comment: Please add this to your question where it can be formatted correctly. When you do that also include the result of `print(cat_fact)`. Also define 'not working'.

Comment: My answer assumes that `cat_fact` is a Python object as  you would get from doing `json.loads(json_str)`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now:

```
for cat_fact in cat_facts_json:

    data = json.dumps(cat_fact)
    insert_query = "insert into cat_facts (data) values (%s) returning data"
    cursor.execute(insert_query, (data,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

I considered your comments @Stefano Frazzetto and @Adrian Klaver.

- json.dumps works !
- I didn't execute the parameters directly in the execute query

I still think, this is a pretty odd syntax with the comma after data:

```
cursor.execute(insert_query, (data,))
```

Comment: Which is the long way around of doing: `insert_query = "insert into cat_facts (data) values (%s) returning data"  cursor.execute(insert_query, (Json(cat_fact),))`. `(data,)` is a tuple and Python syntax requires it to have a comma to distinguish it from just a bracketed value so: `t = (1,) t[0]  1,  t = (1)  t[0] 'int' object is not subscriptable`. If you don't want to do that use a list.