# psycopg3 inserting dict into JSONB field

Tags: python, postgresql, jsonb, psycopg3

I have a table with a `JSONB` field and would like to insert into it using a named dict like so:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (id, json_fld) VALUES (%(id)s, %(json_fld)s)"
conn.execute(sql, {'id':1, 'json_fld': {'a':1,'b':false, 'c': 'yes'}});
```

I tried the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31796332/psycopg2-insert-python-dictionary-as-json) but those all apply to psycopg2 and NOT psycopg3 and they do not work here (notably I tried):

```
conn.execute(sql, {'id':1, 'json_fld': json.dumps({'a':1,'b':false, 'c': 'yes'})});
```

The error remains the same:

> psycopg.ProgrammingError: cannot adapt type 'dict' using placeholder
> '%s' (format: AUTO)

Comment: Read [Adapting Types](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/adapt.html): Section *JSON adaptation*.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver This was the correct answer, if you submit it I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python code to convert `dict` to `jsonb` using `psycopg` JSON adapters described here [JSON adaptation](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/adapt.html) section *JSON adaptation*.

```
import psycopg
from psycopg.types.json import Jsonb

con = psycopg.connect("dbname=test user=postgres")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("insert into json_test values(%s, %s)", 
            [1, Jsonb({'a':1,'b': False, 'c': 'yes'})])
con.commit()
```

This results in:

```
select * from json_test ;

 id |              js_fld              
----+----------------------------------
  1 | {"a": 1, "b": false, "c": "yes"}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this in psycopg3 by converting the dictionary to JSON first using `json.dumps` function.

```
data = {
    'id': 1,
    'json_fld': {'a': 1, 'b': False, 'c': 'yes'}
}

json_data = json.dumps(data['json_fld'])

sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (id, json_fld) VALUES (%(id)s, %(json_fld)s)"

cursor.execute(sql, {'id': data['id'], 'json_fld': json_data})

conn.commit()
```

Comment: You might want to read the docs [Adaptation](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/adapt.html). *JSON adaptation: ...Psycopg requires you to wrap the object to dump as JSON into a wrapper: either psycopg.types.json.Json or Jsonb.*. No need to import and use `json` as that is already done by `psycopg`. Correct your answer or delete it.